# Loading an External .CSS File From Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, utf-8, character-encoding

I've been learning CSS lately, and how to use it along with HTML. I've looked at many of tutorials and solutions to this problem, all of which point towards Firefox being fussy on character encoding. I have set both file, the HTML *and* the CSS, to UTF-8 encoding, but it still doesn't work. *(both files are called test.html or css)*

**HTML**
`<meta charset = "UTF-8">`

**CSS**
`@charset "UTF-8"`

If it is necessary, I have a PasteBin link to their entire codes. *(yes, I have tried the first css line with a semi-colon and without.)*

http://pastebin.com/iprAD44A

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
   
~Computo

Comment: Do you see any error in the firefox console?

Comment: [02:05:28.624] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ file:///D:/CSS/test.html

Comment: `but it still doesn't work` - what exactly isn't working?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the character encoding. Don't even worry about it at this point, it only complicates things for you right now, you can write all the standard CSS in the world and your web pages will work fine without setting encoding types. I have never seen are used the @charset "[encoding choice]" in any style sheet before.

If you are setting encoding types for web pages and assets like style sheets, it is important to have control over the server's response to the client's(browers like Firefox) request. Because the server should be returning the encoding type that you declare.

Comment: Strangely, this seems to have prevailed.

Comment: It is isn't really that strange, it IS important to understand encoding at some point, but not for basic HTML and CSS. By not declaring an encoding type for characters in your HTML and CSS old and modern browsers manage just fine rendering your web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the CSS, based on a Mozilla specific Firefox extension. Also closed off the @charset.

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

**CSS GOES HERE**

}
```